# CakePHP SQL-query count

Tags: sql, cakephp

I have a problem concerning CakePHP SQL-queries. I need to fetch products from the database where shop_id is given and then count the products. All I need is Product.url and its count.

This will do the trick in plain SQL:

```
SELECT url,COUNT(*) as count FROM products GROUP BY url ORDER BY count DESC;
```

This one I used to get all products relating to shops:

```
$this->Product->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Product.shop_id'=>$id)));
```

That works correctly, but I need to convert that SQL-query above to CakePHP.

I tried something like this:

```
$this->Product->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Product.shop_id'=>$id),
                                        'fields'=>array('Product.url','Product.id'),
                                        'order'=>'count DESC',
                                        'group'=>'Product.url'));
```

That returns only an int. But if I run that SLQ-query presented above in mysql server, I get two columns: url and count. How do I get the same results with CakePHP?

Comment: It's usually better to leverage "virtual fields" for this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$data = $this->Post->query(
    "SELECT COUNT(id),MONTH(created) FROM posts GROUP BY YEAR(created), MONTH(created);"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most easiest way to do this:

```
$this->Product->query("SELECT url,COUNT(*) as count FROM products GROUP BY url ORDER BY count DESC;");
```

...at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
$this->Product->virtualFields['CNT_PRODUCTS'] = 0;
$this->Product->find('count', array('conditions' => array('Product.shop_id' => $id),
                                    'fields' => array('Product.id', 'Product.url', 'count(*) as CNT_PRODUCTS'),
                                    'order' => array('CNT_PRODUCTS' => 'DESC'),
                                    'group' => 'Product.url'));
```

Comment: See this link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-in-sql-queries